# Why does Wingdings not function on iOS 5? Why can't I use Wingdings in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, uifont, wingdings

I built a test app. All it does is populate a label on the screen with text and then try and change the font. 90% of the time this works just fine, even when I am using custom fonts that I have imported. However, I have not been able to get [Wingdings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings) to function even though I installed it in my resources folder and added it to the `info.plist`

```
self.theLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Wingdings-Regular" size:64.0f];
```

I thought maybe it was the name I was using, but I ran a test and found that not only is the family Wingdings installed, but Wingdings-Regular is the proper name. I ran experiments where I switched out "Wingdings-Regular" with other variations and noticed that when I do enter something that is garbage, the size is ignored. Using "Wingdings-Regular" the size is not ignored, but the letters show up normally instead of the Symbols I need. How do I fix this problem?

I am pulling my hair out.

Comment: I was not able to get this to work, however I was able to use Unicode to get the symbols I needed out of the Arial font. Still curious why Wingdings does not work, but at least I can finish my project.

Comment: Wingdings did not work for me either. Your unicode idea did work, thankfully. This site has list of unicode characters: http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/index.html#links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unicode is required to access the symbols in Wingdings or other symbol fonts.  See [How to use Wingdings font in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12756623/1712187) for more discussion.  UIKit and Java are both fundamentally based on Unicode.  See http://unicode.org for more details.